# C++ creating a histogram with test score in txt file

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to create a histogram given a txt file that has these scores: 100, 95, 47, 88, 86, 92, 75, 89, 81, 70, 55, 80 what the program needs to do is display a histogram like this:

```
00s:

10s:

20s:

30s:

40s:*

50s:
etc...
```

Here is my code below, what I am having trouble with is simply making sure that the * go into each of the corresponding score percentiles i.e 10s,20s,etc...

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

void Print_Hist();

int main() {
 double nums;
ifstream data("Test_Score.txt");
if(data.is_open()){
    cout << "The file is open" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Check if file exists" << endl;
}  

//  Declare vector<double> vecx
vector<double> vecx;
//  read data from input file to vector vecx,
while(data >> nums)
{
    vecx.push_back(nums);
}

for (int i=0; i < vecx.size(); i++){
    int num = vecx[i];

    if(num < 10){
        cout << "*" << endl; 
    }
    else if(num >= 10 && num < 20){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 20 && num < 30){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 30 && num < 40){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 40 && num < 50){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 50 && num < 60){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 60 && num < 70){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 70 && num < 80){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 80 && num < 90){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num >= 90 && num < 100){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    else if(num = 100){
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }


}

}

void Print_Hist(){
    cout << "00s: " << endl;
    cout << "10s: " << endl;
    cout << "20s: " << endl;
    cout << "30s: " << endl;
    cout << "40s: " << endl;
    cout << "50s: " << endl;
    cout << "60s: " << endl;
    cout << "70s: " << endl;
    cout << "80s: " << endl;
    cout << "90s: " << endl;
    cout << "100: " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  You could replace the entire if/else if/else chain with a single statement `cout << "*" << endl;` because that's what each block of code does.

Comment: You're not actually creating a histogram. For all values read from the file you need to add '1' to the histogram bin that value falls into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do sth like:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class  compare {
public:
   bool operator() (int a, int b) {
      return a / 10 < b / 10;
   }
};

int main() {
   map<int, double, compare> histogram;
   int values[] = {100, 95, 47, 88, 86, 92, 75, 89, 81, 70, 55, 80};
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      histogram[values[i]]++;
      count++;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=10) {
      cout << i << "s:";
      for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i] / count * 10; j++) {
         cout << "*" ;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: how would you do what you just did but using a file that stores the values

Answer (score 0):

If the file will be space delimited you could do it like this (the input file name is, as you can guess is "filename.txt")

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class  compare {
public:
   bool operator() (int a, int b) {
      return a / 10 < b / 10;
   }
};

int main() {
   map<int, double, compare> histogram;
   ifstream f("filename.txt");
   int count;
   while (f) {
      int val;
      f >> val;
      if (!f)
          break;
      histogram[val]++;
      count++;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=10) {
      cout << i << "s:";
      for (int j = 0; j < histogram[i]; j++) {
         cout << "*" ;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```